# How to stop spring gridFsTemplate in between while storing a big file

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, gridfs

I am using spring GridFsTemplate for storing video files. My save function looks like below

```
public String save(String fileName, String contentType, InputStream inputStream, String userName){
        DBObject metaData = new BasicDBObject();
        metaData.put("user", userName);
        return gridFsTemplate.store(inputStream, fileName, contentType, metaData).toString();
    }
```

The above method always get called in a new thread.
I have a requirement that user should be able to stop the uploading of video in between. How can i achieve this with GridFsTemplate ?

Answer (score 0):

GridFSBucket provide the upload stream method, by which i can control over the uploading part.
Below is the code

```
public String saveViaOutputStream(String fileName, InputStream inputStream){
        try {
            GridFSUploadStream gridFSUploadStream = gridFSBucket.openUploadStream(fileName);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int len = 0;
            while ((len = inputStream.read(buffer))!= -1) {
                gridFSUploadStream.write(buffer, 0, len);
            }
            gridFSUploadStream.flush();
            gridFSUploadStream.close();

            return gridFSUploadStream.getObjectId().toString();
        }catch (IOException e){
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
```

I can make it run on a thread and when user want to stop the uploading, i can interrupt that thread.